# Can't call functions in parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, parent

I'm trying to make a call to 2 functions `setListener();` and `addNewBox();` from within an iframe.

I've looked everywhere and tried everything and I can't get it to work.

I don't have access to the head of the parent because it is being constructed in chunks through php require.

This is a rough mockup of what the parent file looks like.

```
<head>
<?php require "head.html" ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php require "content.html" ?>
</body>
```

content.html mockup:

```
<!-- a bunch of boring divs -->
<iframe src="image_editor.html"></iframe>
<script> /* random ajax */ </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //init
    setListener();
    addNewBox();

    function setListener()
    {
            //MAGIC HAPPENS
        }

        function addNewBox()
    {
            //GREATER MAGIC HAPPENS
        }
}
</script>
```

image_editor.html mockup:

```
<body>
<form id="image_form">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#image_form").submit(function(e) {
            //MAGIC HAPPENS HERE

            //re-adds listeners
            window.parent.addNewBox();
            window.parent.setListener();
        }
</script>
</body>
```

I have tried every solution I could find online, from using top, to re-declaring the functions in parent in public format (window.myFunction = function() { };).

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

UPDATE:
After some debugging it seems that the reason the calls aren't working is because execution stop one line before them. Somehow this line "$(".new", window.parent.document).remove();" breaks everything. I now have to figure that one out. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens at least because `setListener()` and `addNewBox()` are not in the global scope of `window.parent`. To fix this you need to move them out of `$(document).ready(function(e) {...}())`.

Comment: Nope, none that are related.

Comment: If one of them cuts the execution before it gets to this part of the code?

Comment: No, its just warning about fb button not loading.

Comment: No, but you were right. The line right before, "$(".new", window.parent.document).remove();" is preventing anything further from being executed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

You can fix it like this:

```
$(window.parent).bind(setListener);
$(window.parent).bind(addNewBox);
```

Hope it helps!